# PHP CURL to VB.net conversion

Tags: php, vb.net, curl, code-conversion

I have a working php code that extracts links but my problem is i don't know how to convert it into a VB.net code as VB.net does not use CURL. Is there any way to convert this? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
$npages=100;
$gg_url = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=' . urlencode(test) . '&filter=0&start=';
$i=1;
$size=0;

$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookie.txt",
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookie.txt",
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3",
CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://www.google.com/",
);

    for ($page = $start; $page < $npages; $page++)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($gg_url.$page.'0');
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        $scraped="";
        $scraped.=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close( $ch );
        $results = array();
        preg_match_all('/a href="([^"]+)" class=l.+?>.+?<\/a>/',$scraped,$results);
        foreach ($results[1] as $url)
        {
        echo "<a href='$url'>$url</a> <br>";
        $i++;
        }
        $size+=strlen($scraped);
    }

echo "Number of results: $i Total KB read: ".($size/1024.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WebClient` object. You should be able to do the same with that guy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx